# How do I combine two rows of same part, but add quantities?

Tags: sql, join, sum

I have table "PICKITEM"

```
PARTID      QTY
A           1
A           3
B           11
C           8
D           5
D           3
```

I need a select statement that will return one line for like PARTIDs and add the qty field to together, yet also return the rest of the lines in the table as is

```
PARTID      QTY
A           4
B           11
C           8
D           8
```

Probably a newb question, but I am new to SQL syntax and queries. Any help in getting me on the right path would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT partid, SUM( qty ) As 'qty' FROM pickitem GROUP BY partid;
```

very basic syntax, no joins needed.

Answer (score 0):

Read the manual for `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT PARTID, SUM(QTY)
FROM PICKITEM
GROUP BY PARTID
```